# Why the maximum size of log file is 2147483648 KB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I understand that the maximum size of Log file is 2TB and Primary one is 16TB but why Maxsize is written as unlimited for the primary while in log file Its 2147483648 KB (2TB)

Comment: What is a problem? You can set another value. Usually log file is not big.

Comment: See the second picture, why Its "Unlimited" for the primary file while Its "2147483648 KB " for the second? The default value should be "unlimited" for both as I didn't specify any values for maxsize in the query.

Comment: In `SIMPLE` recovery model you have very small backup log. In `FULL` recovery model you backup your log file. After backup log file can be rewriten by another logs

Comment: Therefore 2TB for log file is enough. More than enough

Comment: That's not my question. 2147483648 KB is actually 2TB but why Its written in numbers instead of "Unlimited" , that's my question.

Comment: Unlimited is not a 2TB. Your primary file can be more than 2TB (depends on sql server version, usually 16TB!), but this log file is limited to 2 TB

Comment: The primary mdf is *unlimited* so it will grow up to the maximum supported size, the ldf is 2TB because thats the maximum supported size for a log file.  If your asking why *unlimited* is shown rather and 16GB its because Microsoft decided to do it that way.

Comment: @AlexK. I believe I understand now (but I could be wrong) after thinking about it. The maximum is 2TB for logfile, 16 TB for primary file but as mentioned on the MS documentation "For values greater than 2147483647, use larger units" Its not possible to use larger values, that's why they wrote "Unlimited" instead for the primary file.